# Grid View in aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, master-pages

i have code of grid view in aspx.cs it show an error, i cannot understand how it solve, So please anyone can help me? Error picture is attached.[image]

Comment: Do you have a `DataSource` on the .aspx page which is associated with the `GridView`?

Comment: Yes....<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="false" 
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Smaller" DataKeyNames="Logid" >

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `GridView` can just have one `DataSource`. Since you are setting the `DataSource` programmatically remove the `DataSourceID` from the aspx part since that is used for declarative datasource controls like `SqlDataSource` or `ObjectDataSource`.

For example:

```
<asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
  datasourceid="CustomersSource" <-- !!! REMOVE THIS !!! 
  autogeneratecolumns="False"
  emptydatatext="No data available." 
  allowpaging="True" 
  runat="server" DataKeyNames="CustomerID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" 
            InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CustomerID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" 
            SortExpression="CompanyName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" 
            SortExpression="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" 
            SortExpression="LastName" />
    </Columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have applied datasource Id from Aspx page to Grid.
like,

```
DataSourceID="DatasourceId"
```

Use one only.

Answer (score 0):

go in your default.aspx, find the tag that contains the attribute ID="GridView1" and wipe from it the attribute DataSourceID="[SOMETHING]"

Comment: i wrote this... So what i can change in it?<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="false" 
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Smaller" DataKeyNames="Logid" >

Comment: delete << DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" >>

and by the way please study some aspx basics